# How to fetch content from rich text field Contentful

Tags: gatsby, contentful, richtext

I'm trying it out in a test project.
here is from the Index.js

```
const IndexPage = ({data: {posts}}) => {
  return (
  <div>
      <h1>Test Page</h1>
      {posts.edges.map(({node}) => (
        <Card key={node.id} node={node} />
      ))}
  </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage;

export const query = graphql`
query {
  posts: allContentfulPost {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        slug
        content{
           content
         }
        body{
           raw
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

I've copied your suggested code into my template component card.js. Here's when I try to render out the rich text field.

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"

    const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
    const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
    let richTextField;

    const options = {
      renderMark: {
        [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
        },
      renderNode: {
        [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
        [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
            return (
              <>
                <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
                <pre>
                  <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
                </pre>
              </>
            )
          },
        },
    }
    

function Card({ node }) {
    const { body } = node.body
  
    return (
            <article style={{backgroundColor:"red"}}>
               {/* <Img fluid={images[0].FluidObject} alt=""/> */}
               {/* <a href={`/posts/${node.slug}`}>
                   <h2>{node.title}</h2>
               </a>
               <p>
               {node.content.content} 
               </p> */}
               <div>{body && renderRichText(richTextField, options)}</div>
            </article>   
    ) 
  }

export default Card;
```

But it doesn't render out the richTextField. First it was complaining that richTextField was undefined, so I added `let richTextField` in the beginning of the file.

Comment: What does your own component look like? Have you checked the example in [`gatsby-source-contentful` plugin docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#rendering) linked in the previous answer?

Comment: iv'e updated my question @JulioMalves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"

const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>

const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <bold>{text}</bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}

function BlogPostTemplate({ data }) {
  const { bodyRichText } = data.contentfulBlogPost

  return <div>{bodyRichText && renderRichText(richTextField, options)}</div>
}
```

The `options` object, in the end, is a bunch of functions that return custom markup based on your project logic (i.e: `<bold>{text}</bold>` when the rich text has bold styling, etc) so, you only need to render it using:

```
renderRichText(richTextField, options)
```

In your component where you want to render the content, ideally, in a template.

For further details check the [plugin's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#rendering).

Comment: Where are the `options`? You need to pass your queried data into the options object before printing it.

Comment: This is where I get confused. Should I replace ```children``` and ```text```with my queried data? Where do I use the ```const Bold``` and ```const Text```. I would need a guide telling me what every part of this code does ^_^ @FerranBuireu

Comment: oh i see now, yes the ```options```are right before ```function Card```. Didnt show it since it complained I had too much code in my question.

Comment: Put it inside the component (function) you need to parse the content at the rendering time. You just need to return whatever you want in each type of content: `[MARKS.BOLD]: text => <div>{text}</div>,` <-- you are rendering a custom `div`